# Integrating asp.net 4.0 web app into sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I want to use signalr with Sharepoint 2010, but unfortunately this uses .NET 4.0. So I need to make a custom ASP.NET 4.0 webapp and integrate it with Sharepoint. What are my options for this?

I saw a link that listed ways such as application pages etc but can't fidn that now.

Also, assume I build an "asp.net webapp".

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find [this article](http://spmatt.wordpress.com/2012/04/12/harnessing-signalr-in-sharepoint/) useful.

Comment: I actually saw this link just after my question, and it helps immensely. WCF the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2010 is asp.net 3.5 and asp.net 4.0 can't run in the same application pool. You might be able to run seperate virtual directories as seperate apppool, but it's a hack and you just risk breaking both SharePoint and your app.

My recommendation would be to keep the 4.0 web app completely seperate from SharePoint. Don't try to integrate it as application pages or anything.

It may run on the same servers, but PLEASE put it as a seperate IIS site.

You can then create web parts or whatever you want to contain the HTML and javascript to talk to that web app and integrate these with SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

With out knowing the exact nature of what you are trying to do with your "integration" it's hard to give possible solutions.  Two possible options that come to mind are:

Use the [Javascript Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185006.aspx).  You don't have the power that you do with the standard object model, but you can still create SharePoint applications that can do quite a bit.

Someone has also attempted to create a .net 2.0 compatible client library.  You can find that [here](https://github.com/robink-teleopti/SignalR).  I have not used it and cannot speak to how well it works.
Good luck!